# how to use install imagemagick to use php on windows 8.1

Tags: php, ajax, phpmyadmin, imagemagick

I dont know how to work with image magick and also how to call image magick commands using php ,What are the supportive packages for integrate with php.

Answer (score 0):

I uses exec("convert input output");

It also depends if you are talking about Imagemagick or Imagick and what version you have.

I have quite a lot of Imagemagick with php examples and information on my website [www.rubblewebs.co.uk](http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk)

Edit:
As long as you installed Imagemagick on your PC wamp should find it ( I use xampp without a problem ). You just write a normal php page with the exec() command and it should work. If you are using version 7 I would replace convert with magick. Start with something simple like exec("convert input.jpg output.png"); and see what happens.

Did you see this and can you confirm which you are using as there can be some confusion: "It also depends if you are talking about Imagemagick or Imagick and what version you have."